# How to output git commit id to all logback logs with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I am using SpringBoot with Logback along with the git commit id maven plugin. How do I configure logback and SpringBoot to include the git commit id that the actuator returns in my log output? I want each line of output to include the git commit id of the boot app that generated the line of output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the `git-commit-id-plugin` creates a file named `git.properties` in the root of the classpath containing lots of properties, including `git.commit.id`.

You can [import these properties](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingProps) in logback's config file, and access the properties anywhere within the logback configuration.

For example, you can use it within a pattern like this:

```xml
<configuration>

    <!-- Expose the properties from the file generated by git-commit-id-plugin -->
    <property resource="git.properties"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} ${git.commit.id} - %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Or (since you tagged this question with `logstash-logback-encoder`) you can include it in a JSON field via [custom fields](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#global-custom-fields), or via the [pattern provider](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#pattern-json-provider) like this:

```xml
<configuration>

    <!-- Expose the properties from the file generated by git-commit-id-plugin -->
    <property resource="git.properties"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>{"commitId":"${git.commit.id}"}</pattern>
                </pattern>
            ...
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: The custom field `${git.commit.id}` only working with `LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder`, but not with `LogstashEncoder`. Is there any reason?

Comment: Able to add `git.commit.id` to `LogstashEncoder` as follows. `<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <version>${git.commit.id}</version>
        </encoder>`